# is there a way to insert space between the characters of a string based on length using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to write a function that inserts space based on the length of the strings in a column.

I have a dataframe with two columns one with postcodes and the other with the length of those postcodes.  Shown below:

```
    new_pstl_cd length
  1 SS55HA       6
  2 BD108EG      7
  3 LS15HU       6
  4 W19PX        5
```

I want to insert a space so that the column becomes

```
   new_pstl_cd  
 1 SS5 5HA
 2 BD10 8EG         
 3 LS1 5HU
 4 W1 9PX
```

I have tried the below code without sucess:

```
 def insert_space(charachter):
      if postcode_test['length'] == 6:
          return (postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'].str[0:3]+ charachter + postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'].str[3:])
      if postcode_test['length'] == 5:
          return (postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'].str[0:2]+ charachter + postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'].str[3:])
      else:
           return (postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'].str[0:4]+ charachter + postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'].str[4:])
```

How would I write a function using the lengths to do this? Please note that in this case it will always be the last 3 characters being separated

Comment: I know your question is "with Pandas", but personally I would just write a Python function to implement something like this, then `.map` it over the Series. Otherwise you can use `.where` or `.mask` with callable arguments, or just use boolean filtering with `.loc`.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement on separation based on `length`.  Did you just want the last 3 characters separated? Please [edit] your question to clarify how the space is inserted for difference `length`s.

Comment: @shadowtalker please attempt an answer for `length=7` then, while keeping in mind what the results for `length=5` and `length=6`.  We ask clarification because it matters.  Perhaps the problem is not asking for clarification, but that people take things too personally.

Comment: @r.ook they didn't ask about `length=7`, why would you attempt such a thing?

Comment: @shadowtalker Then one of us don't understand the question.  If you want to provide an answer instead, please feel free to do so.  I personally think being helpful means getting it right the first time.

Comment: @shadowtalker I'm asking length = 7 as well I just didn't write it in my code as it would be same as length = 6 and length 5 and none of them is working

Comment: @r.ook https://stackoverflow.com/a/61391981/2954547

Comment: @Yags, is it safe to say you want the words split in half? On odd lengths like 3, 5, 7, 9... what would be the expected outcome? The first half will be longer or shorter? The issue I'm having problem understanding is the difference in how `5` and `7` behaves, hence the question.

Comment: @r.ook  BD108EG      would be BD10 8EG and  W19PX        would be W1 9PX as explained above. The length will never be less than 5 or more than 7

Comment: @shadowtalker exactly - your answer fails when `length=7`.  Do you see the value of asking for clarification now?

Comment: @Yags what about 3, 9, 11, etc? Quang Hoang's answer should fit your need already.  But if you want to understand how to handle it by `length`, you need to clarify how you want it handled.

Comment: I assume the OP is intelligent enough to figure out how to adapt one of the 4 methods in my answer for their needs. I answered the Pandas question, you can go ahead and work on the string splitting algorithm. @r.ook

Comment: e.g. given a string of `ABCDEF12345` of `length=11`, what is the outcome? `ABCDEF 12345`? `ABCDE F12345`? `ABCD  EF12345`? `ABCDEF12 345`? That's what I'm having trouble extending to `length=n`.

Comment: @r.ook the length cannot be less than 5 and more than 7

Comment: Then I suggest you use @QuantHoang's approach.  I don't see the reason for you to use a bunch of `if/else` statement on `length`.  You are always splitting by the `[-3:]` slice.  It'll just complicate the matter.  If you just want to understand the nuances of `apply`ing a function on `pandas` based on a column, @shadowtalker got you covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't even need `length`:

```
df['new_pstl_cd'] = df.new_pstl_cd.str[:-3] + ' ' + df.new_pstl_cd.str[-3:]
```

Output:

```
  new_pstl_cd  length
1     SS5 5HA       6
2    BD10 8EG       7
3     LS1 5HU       6
4      W1 9PX       5
```

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

This `if`/`elif` code you tried reflects a common misunderstanding about how Pandas works.

`if` only ever accepts a *single* Boolean value, i.e. `True` or `False`. `postcode_test['length'] == 6` is a Pandas Series object, i.e. a collection of *many* Boolean values. It doesn't even make sense to use it as an input to `if`, as the error message you surely saw explains.

You need to figure out some way to apply an operation to some rows, but not other rows, but you can't use `if`. Pandas actually offers *several* ways to achieve this.

## Possible solutions

As always, **DO NOT COPY AND PASTE CODE THAT YOU DO NOT UNDERSTAND**. Refer to the [library documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) for help. This code is **untested**; it might contain bugs and there is no warranty attached.

### Boolean subsetting

The simplest method is probably with boolean subsetting, which is more or less what you were trying to do originally.

```py
postcode_len_6 = postcode_test['length'] == 6
postcode_len_5 = postcode_test['length'] == 5
```

`postcode_len_6` and `postcode_len_5` are Series objects with Boolean elements. Their elements correspond to elements of `postcode_test['length']` Series, whose elements in turn correspond to rows of the `postcode_test` Dataframe.

You can use these Series objects as per the [indexing and selecting data guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html):

```py
postcode_test.loc[postcode_len_6, 'new_pstl_cd'] = \
    postcode_test.loc[postcode_len_6, 'new_pstl_cd'].str[:3] + ' '+ \
    postcode_test.loc[postcode_len_6, 'new_pstl_cd'].str[3:]

postcode_test.loc[postcode_len_5, 'new_pstl_cd'] = \
    postcode_test.loc[postcode_len_5, 'new_pstl_cd'].str[:2] + ' '+ \
    postcode_test.loc[postcode_len_5, 'new_pstl_cd'].str[2:]
```

### Using the "mask" method

This one can be unintuitive sometimes, so make sure you read the [user's](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking) [guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#mask) and the [API documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.Series.where).

You begin, as before, by first finding the rows where the lengths are 5 or 6:

```py
postcode_len_6 = postcode_test['length'] == 6
postcode_len_5 = postcode_test['length'] == 5
```

But instead of the big incantation with `.loc`, you use `.mask` instead:

```py
postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'] = postcode_test['new_pstl_cd']\
    .mask(postcode_len_6, lambda s: s.str[:3]+' '+s.str[3:])

postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'] = postcode_test['new_pstl_cd']\
    .mask(postcode_len_5, lambda s: s.str[:2]+' '+s.str[2:])
```

### Mapping a plain Python function

Another solution is to write a "scalar-valued" Python function that simply operates on strings.

```py
def make_new_postcode(p):
    if len(p) == 5:
        p = p[:2] + ' ' + p[2:]
    elif len(p) == 6:
        p = p[:3] + ' ' + p[3:]
    return p

postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'] = postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'].map(make_new_postcode)
```

### Applying a plain Python function

You can also apply a function row-wise if you really want to re-use the existing `"length"` column:

```py
def make_new_postcode(row):
    l= row['length']
    p= row['new_pstl_cd']
    if l == 5:
        p = p[:2] + ' ' + p[2:]
    elif l == 6:
        p = p[:3] + ' ' + p[3:]
    return p

postcode_test['new_pstl_cd'] = postcode_test[['length', 'new_pstl_cd']].apply(make_new_postcode, axis=1, result_type='reduce')
```